# Question about DNS priorities when connected to VPN

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7, vpn

So I'm connected to a Windows VPN and I want the following conditions to be met:

1. I want my internet connection to tunnel through to the VPN's internet connection (i.e. I don't want to use the machine's local network internet connection)
2. I want the DNS servers on my local network to take priority over the DNS servers from my VPN network

How can I set this up on Windows 7?

Comment: What kind of VPN are you using? Each client implements this differently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do both. Setting the first option would prevent access to the local network (where the DNS servers may reside) which is how you get to the local internet connection (the other place the DNS may reside)

Comment: I was afraid of this. Basically I want to use the internet connection from the VPN but still be able to access local network intranet sites by using the local network's DNS server.

Comment: If you want to access local resources but not the web, you could try changing your default route to the VPN endpoint, but leave routing for the local network in place (and don't prevent access to local network.

Comment: can you give me a quick tutorial on how to set this up in Windows 7? Perhaps edit your original answer to show this solution.

Comment: I guess actually what would be the best solution is to be able to selectively route internet traffic through each adapter based on which DNS server is matched.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot. I don't use Ms VPN.  I will say, what you describe in your comment would be done with routing changes